# Upload file Action class with ModelDriven in Struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, model-driven

I'm studying Struts 2 and get an issue: cannot upload file in `ActionClass` that implements `ModelDriven`

#### Product.java

```
    public class Product {
    String name, image;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, String image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

#### ProductAction.java

```
    public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Product> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5538774764479904797L;

    File image;

    public void setImage(File file) {
        System.out.println("SET IMAGE");
    }

    public String submitPost() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println("POST");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    Product p = new Product();

    @Override
    public Product getModel() {
        return p;
    }

}
```

I want to upload in `ProductAction`. But if `ProductAction` implements `ModelDriven`, method `setImage()` not called, and if `ProductAction` doesn't implement `ModelDriven`, it works normal. How can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of the `image` to `File` and getters/setters. When you use `ModelDriven` you don't need to use action properties. Action classes also known as controllers don't need to keep the state. Struts pushes your model to the top of the `valueStack` before populating it with request parameters.

```
String name;
File image; 
//getters and setters
```